# Load JSON locale in sails js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have set the english locale file like this in sails js

```
{
"api": {
"error": {
  "forbidden": "Access not granted",
  "notfound": "Could not find resource",
  "authentication": {
    "failure": "Authentication failure",
    "invalid_token": "Invalid token"
  }
 }
}
```

How can I dynamically load the values in my controllers, services, ... ?
I'm using sails version 0.11.2

Answer (score -1):

You can use built in Internationalization

[Sails.js Locales](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/internationalization/locales)

You put your json in `config/locales/en.json`. But it should be simple dictionary:

```
{
  "api.error.forbidden": "Access not granted",
  "api.error.notfound": "Could not find resource",
  "api.error.authentication.failure": "Authentication failure",
  "api.error.authentication.invalid_token": "Invalid token"
}
```

Than you can use it in Services or Controllers:

```
req.__('api.error.forbidden'); // => Access not granted
```

Or in views

```
<%= __('api.error.forbidden') %>
```

There are some more options like locales with params. [Check out documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/internationalization)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this in the documentation but was wondering if it was possible to do it this way.